# @IntegrationTest properties in a suite are not reloaded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I've put an `@IntegrationTest` annotation on every test, and sometimes I use it to add properties to the environment. When running all tests together, it seems that only the properties encountered in the first `@IntegrationTest` annotation are used, so some tests are failing. Is there a way to force a reload of those properties?

This is an example of my usage:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=TestApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("some.property=true")
public class SomeIntegrationTest {
```

Comment: How do you determine which `@IntegrationTest` properties are used, i.e. which test class is loaded first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot Applications under test are started just once for all tests, which is a good thing regarding test performance. If you want to start another application with a different property set, you have to write another Spring Boot application class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MetricsTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MetricsTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In the integration test, you reference that other class. In addition you have to set a different port than the first application has, and you can add the properties that differ from the properties of the first application:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=MetricsTestApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=8091","batch.metrics.enabled=true"})
```

Our MetricsTestApplication with the different property set is now started under port 8091.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation @IntegrationTest annotation is ["signifying that the tests are integration tests (and therefore require an application to startup "fully loaded" and listening on its normal ports)"](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/).

If you want to use reloadable properties, you should use [EnvironmentTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-environment-test-utilities).

eg.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

@Before
public void before() {
    EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment(ctx, "test.value:myValue");
}

@Test
public void testGreeting() {
    assertThat(env.getProperty("test.value"), comparesEqualTo("myValue"));
}
```

Comment: Is the above the whole solution? I have tried to add this, but it doesn't seem to add the properties at all. Is there a class-level annotation that is supposed to get this running?

Comment: @Istvan EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment has been removed in Boot 2.2 , any idea what to use instead?